# Jquery function to apply CSS properties

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am trying to apply CSS properties to all div but except one. I need to apply opacity to all the divs except one div.

HTML

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="nike">3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So which one? Show us some code.

Comment: Hi all, Please find the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/2/

HTML

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div class="nike">3</div>
<div>4</div>
```

CSS

```
div:not(.nike){opacity:0.2}
```

**Using Jquery**  Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6V8hr/3/

```
$('div:not(.nike)').css('opacity','0.2')
```

Comment: i love the CSS-only approach, but you should provide disclaimer this does not work on IE8 and below.

Comment: You know, the question asks for a jQuery solution. But then again, this question is, for lack of a better term, "booty". So +1 for you, since I wasn't aware `:not` was a thing in CSS.

Comment: @Deekey: Could you please tell me how to use this in jQuery? Thanks

Comment: @James if the answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the tick

Answer (score 1):

Alright I normally don't respond to questions without code, but since this is so easy:

Give the `div` you don't want affected an extra class:

```
<div class="DontOpacityMePlease">No touchy!</div>
```

Create a class in CSS for what opacity you want to apply to all the other divs:

```
.AwesomeOpacityTime {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Then make your jQuery as such:

```
$('div').not('.DontOpacityMePlease').addClass('AwesomeOpacityTime');
```

This gives complete flexibility, and you can add / remove the class as you wish.